# How to edit customUI (add context menu button) in office add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, contextmenu, office-addins, ribbonx

Hi I just created a office add-in to search acronym' meanings in an API. I need to allow the user to search it directly by the document selecting some text and right click on it and pressing a button on the context menu.

I have tried creating a customUI14.xml file to edit the context menu of the document but I don't really know if I can add it to the add-in and how to do it.

I'm developing it using visual studio 2017 with the official office developer tools.

This is an example of what I need:

[image: Context menu]

[image: searchs on add-in]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the functionality that you've described by creating *add-in commands*, which can be achieved by customizing your add-in's manifest XML file. This article in the docs describes how to do this: [Create add-in commands in your manifest for Excel, Word, and PowerPoint.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands)  In particular, [Step 6: Add ExtensionPoint elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-6-add-extensionpoint-elements) in the article is especially relevant to your scenario, including (especially) the **Menu controls** subsection within **Step 6**.

If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you review the article that I've linked to above. If you run into issues when you attempt to implement add-in commands for your add-in, please post specifics about your issue here on SO.

Comment: Yeah it worked, there is also an example I found (for excel) but really similar for a word add-in in this link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Excel/Manifest/ExcelAddinWithCommandsOnDataTab.xml